# geopy does not show correct output

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, geopy

I am calculating latitudes and longitudes from zip code.

I have installed `geopy`

```
pip install geopy
```

In my code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
def get_lat_lng(zip_code):
    lat, lng = False, False
    geocoder = GoogleV3()
    location = geocoder.geocode(query=str(zip_code))
    if location:
        print location
        lat, lng = location.latitude, location.longitude
    return lat, lng
```

When I call above method and I am giving zip code of Lahore,Pakistan which is 54000.

```
get_lat_lng(54000)
```

Out put of latitude and longitude is:

```
(46.975033, 31.994583)
```

Actual latitude and longitude of Lahore are

```
31.5546° N, 74.3572° E
```

And on print of location I got:

```
Mykolaiv, Mykolaivs'ka oblast, Ukraine, 54000
```

What can be issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could get it to work was to use the components keyword passing a dict of country code and locality:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
def get_lat_lng(zip_code):
    geocoder = GoogleV3()
    location = geocoder.geocode(query=str(zip_code),components={"country": "PK","locality":"lahore"})
    if location:
        print location._address
        lat, lng = location.latitude, location.longitude
    return lat, lng

print(get_lat_lng(54000))
```

Which outputs:

```
Lahore, Pakistan
(31.55460609999999, 74.3571581)
```

The other option is to try the `region=` keyword and/or pass the domain explicitly something other than the default `maps.google.com`.

Even setting `exactly_one` to False:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
def get_lat_lng(zip_code):
    lat, lng = False, False
    geocoder = GoogleV3()
    location = geocoder.geocode(query=str(zip_code), exactly_one=False)
    if location:
        print [loc.address for loc in location]
print(get_lat_lng(54000))
```

Does not return any match.

```
[u"Mykolaiv, Mykolaivs'ka oblast, Ukraine, 54000", u'54000 Nancy, France', u'54000, Thailand', u'Kampung Datuk Keramat, 54000 Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia', u'Tlalnepantla Centro, 54000 Tlalnepantla, M\xe9x., Mexico', u'54000, Broken Bow, OK 74728, USA', u'54000, Oklahoma, USA']
```

Comment: https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/ this documentation is also helpful for latitude and longitude on base of city.